# Create single list with multiple instances of objects from second list in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to build a list of tiles for a board game from an xml file which contains a description of the tiles.  The xml file describes each tile type, and the number of tiles of that type.

So far, I've got the following code which creates a list with exactly one of each tile type:

```
    [Tile(el.id) for el in <tile descriptions>]
```

I'd like to create a list with the appropriate number of each tile, e.g. something like this:

```
    [Tile(el.id) * <el.n_tiles> for el in <tile descriptions>]
```

Is there an elegant one-liner to do this, or do I need to do it long-hand by creating a list for each tile type and then concatenating?

Comment: In other words, you want the elements of the returned list to be themselves lists, each of length `el.n_tiles`?  If so, consider NPE's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
[Tile(el.id) for el in <tile descriptions> for _ in range(el.n_tiles)]
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted will repeat the *same* inner list multiple times:

```
[Tile(el.id) * <el.n_tiles> for el in <tile descriptions>]
```

Instead, use an inner list comprehension:

```
[[Tile(el.id) for i in range(<el.n_tiles>)] for el in <tile descriptions>]
```

If the goal is to create a single concatenated list, the you can use a list comprehension with nested for-loops:

```
[Tile(el.id) for el in <tile descriptions> for i in range(<el.n_tiles>)]
```

When you're a little more advanced, the same effect (list flattening) can be achieved using [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Hope this helps.  Happy gaming :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't make this work as is...is the "r range" a typo?  Without the "r" it ran, but I still struggled to make it work.  Will read up on inner list comprehensions :-).

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.  It's fixed now :-)

Comment: Thanks.  Same typo in the second example now...copy and paste error?